# Very Sleepy profiler confuses mere variables as functions, among other issues

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, profiling, verysleepy

I've been looking for a C profiler for Windows, that will allow me to inspect time spent in the level of source-code lines, as opposed to just at the level of functions. This is in order to find hotspots in the program that can be optimized.

Very Sleepy looks great for this purpose. However, in the Source view, it doesn't seem that the number of time spent per line of code actually adds up to the 100% of Exclusive time for the function.

For example, Very Sleepy says we spent 18.50s Exclusive time in the function. But adding up all of the time durations specified in the Source view for that function, only adds up to about 10s.

This is how I compile the program:

```
gcc -IC:/msys64_new/mingw64/include *.c -o plane.exe -g -gdwarf-2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -LC:/msys64_new/mingw64/lib -lShlwapi
```

I then open Very Sleepy through the GUI and sample the running process for exactly 100 seconds.

I'm using Very Sleepy CS 0.90. I'm running Windows 7 and using the Mingw-w64 subsystem of MSYS2.

**EDIT:**

I've also noticed two additional weird things. First of all, Very Sleepy displays some functions without their name, but does recognize them as part of the profiled module.

Secondly, **Very Sleepy seems to think a few variables are actually functions**. For example:

[image]

`extension_module_file_suffix` is **not a function**, it's a variable. What's going on?

Comment: Optimization makes it difficult for debuggers to match lines of C code to chunks of assembly code, and makes it hard to match variable names to values. I assume that the same applies to a profiler. You might try `-Og` instead of `-O2`, since `-Og` performs some optimization, while still being friendly to debuggers.

Comment: Do you have (small) reproducers for these issues?